# Write to GDAL raster to HDF5

Tags: python, gdal, hdf, hdf5

Is there a way to write a GDAL raster to a HDF4 or HDF5 dataset using GDAL? I have found many examples that show how to read HDF datasets, but none on how to write them.

Comment: HDF5 is an optional driver and is read only, HDF4 supports creation, but I'm not sure if the HDF4 driver is in a default install. GDAL can be installed from a number of sources, your distro may not have the driver which you will need to add manually. Have a read of https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/index.html which tabulates the capabilities of each driver. Theoretically if you use GDAL_Translate (or QGIS::Raster::Translate) and specify the output driver as HDF4 https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/hdf4.html#raster-hdf4 you should be able to convert your existing raster in another format to HDF4.

Comment: Thanks! I'm running GDAL 3.1.2 in python via the conda-forge distribution. When looking at my HDF4 driver metadata, I've noticed that the `DCAP_CREATE` and `DCAP_CREATECOPY` features are not enabled. Do you know if there is a way that I can install the creation-enabled version of the driver?

Comment: Is that Linux? Perhaps http://hdfeos.org/software/gdal.php would help. I'm on Windows and use the GISInternals download https://www.gisinternals.com/release.php which contains gdal_HDF4.dll gdal_HDF4Image.dll in the gdalplugins directory.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10. To be clear @Micheal Stimson, can you create a HDF4 file using your setup? Here is some example python code:
`import gdal`
`driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('HDF4')`
`dst_ds = driver.Create('test.hdf', xsize=512, ysize=512)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, I get *`ERROR 6: GDALDriver::Create() ... no create method implemented for this format`* in both 32bit and 64bit GDAL for HDF4 **but** driver **HDF4Image** will create a HDF4 raster.

To test your installed drivers use `GDALInfo --formats` and you should see a full list of the available formats:

```
Supported Formats:
  HDF4 -raster- (ros): Hierarchical Data Format Release 4
  HDF4Image -raster- (rw+): HDF4 Dataset
  VRT -raster- (rw+v): Virtual Raster
  GTiff -raster- (rw+vs): GeoTIFF
  NITF -raster- (rw+vs): National Imagery Transmission Format
  RPFTOC -raster- (rovs): Raster Product Format TOC format
... and more to follow
```

The `HDF4` driver is ros which means *read only*, the `HDF4Image` is rw+ which means read, write and create.

Comment: Using HDF4Image works, thank you. On a related note, do you know how to create a name subdataset for the HDF4Image file?

Comment: No I don't know how to create a subdataset, it's not a task that I've done before. The API https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal.Dataset-class.html has GetSubDatasets() to get a reference to all the suddatasets in the raster but no SetSubDataset method. A subdataset is not a *band* as each can have differing extent, pixel type and cell size. Perhaps it's something simple like specifying the name in the form *HDF4_SDS:subdataset_type:file_name:subdataset_index*; if you have an existing HDF4 you could use GDALInfo to get the name strings and see if that works, if not please post a new question.